# PHP: join values of nested subarrays by keys

Tags: php, arrays

The past few days I've been puzzled by the following and can't seem to come up with an elegant solution.

I have an array like this, where each subarray has its key prefixed by a hash symbol and each (sub)array has a varying nest depth:

```
Array(
    [#a1] => Array(
            [key1] => a1-1
            [key2] => a1-2
            [#b1] => Array(
                    [key1] => b1-1
                    [key2] => b1-2
                )
            [#b2] => Array(
                    [key1] => b2-1
                    [key2] => b2-2
                    [#c1] => Array(
                            [key1] => c1-1
                            [key2] => c1-2
                        )
                    [#c2] => Array(
                            [key1] => c2-1
                            [key2] => c2-2
                        )
                )
        )
    [#a2] => Array(...)
)
```

I need to some way to walk over each possible nested route (e.g #a1 - #b2 - #c1 but also #a1 - #b2 - #c2) and merge equal keys DURING the route in an array specific for that route. The keys of the resulting array aren't important.

Something like this:

```
Array(

    // Follow path #a1 #b1
    [] = Array(
            [key1] = Array(a1-1, b1-1)
            [key2] = Array(a1-2, b1-2)
        )

    // Follow path #a1 #b2 #c1
    [] = Array(    
            [key1] = Array(a1-1, b2-1, c1-1)
            [key2] = Array(a1-2, b2-2, c1-2)
        )

    // Follow path #a1 #b2 #c2
    [] = Array(    
            [key1] = Array(a1-1, b2-1, c2-1)
            [key2] = Array(a1-2, b2-2, c2-2)
        )

    // Follow path #a2 ...
    [] = Array(...)

    )
)
```

I've been thinking about `array_merge_recursive`, `array_walk_recursive`, `recursive foreaches` but couldn't put them together in something that actually works...

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try using usort() (http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php), example:

```
function compare_id($a, $b) {
    if ($a['id'] == $b['id']) return 0;
    return ($a['id'] < $b['id']) ? -1 : 1;
}

$a = [
    ['id' => 3, 'item' => 'pc'],
    ['id' => 1, 'item' => 'mouse'],
    ['id' => 2, 'item' => 'kb'],
];

usort($a, 'compare_id');

var_dump($a);
```

Comment: I'm wondering how that will generate the output as requested?